# Excel suddenly gobbling memory, 500MB per cell edited?

Tags: microsoft-excel, memory, virus

Excel is suddenly very slow on my system.  I've rebooted, and started a new file, and it's not made a difference.  Each time I input some text into a cell and hit enter, there's a 2-3 second pause before it moves to the next cell.

If I have task manager open at the same time I can see its memory usage going up by about 500MB each time I change a cell...

Dell XPS 9720, Windows 11 & Office 365, all recently updated.

Any ideas?  I hope I'm wrong but I suspect a virus - one that's come down in a malicious excel file that I've opened in the last few days maybe.  The built in Windows defender hasn't detected anything, should I try something else - what's good these days?

Comment: Try to repair Office by right-click on it in *Control Panel > Programs and Features*. Defender is usually as good as anything else, but you could try [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/). Have you installed any add-ons to Excel?

Comment: I deleted some recently opened files out of my AppData Roaming XLSTART folder and that seems to fix the issue.  I did install AbleBits about 6 months ago but have had no problems with it until now so I'm not sure if that is related.

Comment: If you automatic startup items in XLSTART, this explains the problem.